# Receive the name of a list element from function input

Tags: r, list, yaml, names, rlang

Via a .yml file I load in a number of file paths to different data frames.
They are structured in a named list. Here a very simplified version:

```
settings_list <- list(survey = list(df1 = "path",
                                df2 = "path2",
                                df3 = "path3",
                                df4 = "path4"))
```

With the structure:

```
> str(settings_list)
List of 1
  $ survey:List of 3
..$ df1: chr "path"
..$ df2: chr "path2"
..$ df3: chr "path3"
..$ df4: chr "path4"
```

As the dfs don't differ too much in their structure, I have written a function, that takes a single data frame and cleans it.

```
foo_cleaning(path = settings_list$survey$df3)
```

I would then use purrr::map() to loop over all elements of settings_list$survey

What I would like to add to the function is the option to save the cleaned df as a separate object with the name from the list to the global env. (so in this case an object named "df3"). I know, I could simply store them all in a list, but for different reasons, I would also like to include this option in my function.

I basically have the code for this implemented,
however, I'm only struggling to extract the correct name from the function input.

```
names(settings_list$survey$df3)
NULL #desired output: "df3"
```

While applying names to the higher level of the list would give me the whole vector of names,
but how could I extract only the name that corresponds to settings_list$survey$df3?

```
names(settings_list$survey)
[1] "df1" "df2" "df3" "df4"
```

Alternatively, how could I convert the function input settings_list$survey$df3 as a string so that I could use regex to extract the last part of it?

Comment: Concerning the alternative approach:
rlang::as_label(enexpr( path )) returns me at least the whole path argument as a string, so that I can start extracting the last part. But I'm still interested to know if it is possible to extract the name directly.

Comment: But if you are using it to map over all the elements you don't need the name. If you want to work with characters, why not use bracket notation, I.e. `settings_list$survey[["df3"]]`?

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use `match.call`

```r
foo_cleaning <- function(x) {
  y <- as.list(match.call())$x
  result <- as.character(y)[length(as.character(y))]
  cat("Item", result, "requested")
}

foo_cleaning(settings_list$survey$df3)
#> Item df3 requested
```

However, this is unlikely to work well with something like `map`, because `map`  doesn't work by passing all the named elements using `$` notation. In fact, if you try this function with `map` you get:

```r
purrr:::map(settings_list$survey, foo_cleaning)
#> Item i requested
#> Item i requested
#> Item i requested
#> Item i requested
```

A better way to do this would be to allow your function to take an object and its name. For example:

```r
foo_cleaning <- function(x, x_nm) {
  cat("Item", x_nm, "requested\n")
  # Do cleaning with x
}
```

If you think this seems pointless, consider that you can clean all the data frames and have their names used inside the function by doing:

```r
purrr::map2(settings_list$survey, names(settings_list$survey), foo_cleaning)
#> Item df1 requested
#> Item df2 requested
#> Item df3 requested
#> Item df4 requested
```

Incidentally, directly assigning a variable to the global environment in the way you suggest is very problematic in user-facing R code, as it would be very easy to over-write a user's other variables, and is not expected behaviour for an R function.

<sup>Created on 2022-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>